# Can I mix a ZeroMQ TCP/UDP server with a regular BSD TCP/UDP socket client?

Tags: sockets, networking, zeromq

Can I start a ZeroMQ TCP/UDP server and communicate with it using a regular BSD TCP/UDP socket client?

I have a few machines talking to each other, some depending on libraries with low-level socket clients that are otherwise hard to migrate to ZMQ.

Comment: The ZMQ protocol is built on top of "normal" networking, so yes, you can implement that protocol yourself if you desire to.

Comment: A new yet undocumented feature named ZMQ_DGRAM should allow that for UDP now as well. It requires to compile the library with 'drafts' enabled. Have not found a good example yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Q** : *"Can I start a ZeroMQ TCP/UDP server and communicate with it using a regular BSD TCP/UDP socket client?"*

**A :** Yes, but...

Well, **there is nothing like** a "***TCP/UDP server***" in ZeroMQ. ZeroMQ uses high-level behaviour archetypes `{ PUSH/PULL | PUB/SUB | REQ/REP | ... | PAIR/PAIR }`, for which one may choose one or more ( yes, a **`PUB`** sender may get delivered messages to all of `vmci://` and `ipc://` and `pgm://` and `tcp://` **`SUB`**-agents at the same "socket"-archetype at once ) **`transport-classes`**, right due to the fact, that the abstracted `transport-class` data-pumps are the hidden but "specialised" component that handle all the hidden, low-level details - each one a bit different, for serving each particular ***transport-class*** as needed with individual data-pumps' `transport-class`-specific details :
 **`{ inproc:// | ipc:// | tipc:// | tcp:// | pgm:// | epgm:// | norm:// | vmci:// }`**.

---

Yet, there is a "special" **`Socket`**-archetype that may "talk" to non-ZeroMQ counterparties, thus can serve the needs right for you:

> **ZMQ_STREAM**
>
> A socket of type **`ZMQ_STREAM`** is used to send and receive TCP data from a non-ØMQ peer, when using the **`tcp://`** transport. A **`ZMQ_STREAM`** socket can act as client and/or server, sending and/or receiving TCP data asynchronously.
>
> When receiving TCP data, a **`ZMQ_STREAM`** socket shall prepend a message part containing the routing **`id`** of the originating peer to the message before passing it to the application. Messages received are fair-queued from among all connected peers.
>
> When sending TCP data, a **`ZMQ_STREAM`** socket shall remove the first part of the message and use it to determine the routing **`id`** of the peer the message shall be routed to, and unroutable messages shall cause an `EHOSTUNREACH` or `EAGAIN` error.
>
> To open a connection to a server, use the `zmq_connect` call, and then fetch the socket routing **`id`** using the **`zmq_getsockopt()`** call with the **`ZMQ_ROUTING_ID`** option.
>
> To close a specific connection, send the routing id frame followed by a zero-length message.
>
> When a connection is made, a zero-length message will be received by the application. Similarly, when the peer disconnects (or the connection is lost), a zero-length message will be received by the application.
>
> You must send one routing id frame followed by one data frame. The `ZMQ_SNDMORE` flag is required for routing **`id`** frames but is ignored on data frames.

Just be aware of the fair-queue handling of all the ZMQ_STREAM connected peers on incoming direction.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are a true ZMQ ambassador!

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays ZeroMQ also supports DGRAM. See here: [zmq_udp.txt](https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/blob/master/doc/zmq_udp.txt). So besides regular TCP there's also regular UDP.